# Check that $|x|=\max\{-x,x\}=\max\{-x,x,0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-value

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $|x|=\max\{-x,x\}$, is correct also $|x|=\max\{-x,0,x\}$?

Comment: Though this is correct why would you want to make your set bigger if you already getting same result on observing a smaller set.... Is there any specific reason?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, thanks.. it's just a thought

Comment: Fine fine... :)

Comment: Well, $x$ is what, a real number?  Then take cases, depending on the sign of $x$.  Or $x$ is merely an element in a vector lattice (and "max" is the least upper bound)?  Then the question may be more interesting.

Comment: @GEdgar `Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$`.

Comment: @mle sorry if this is a dum question, but is your max a function that chooses between 3 input arguments? Sorry if this is really dum, but I am having issue understanding your questions. I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|x|\geq 0$, because $x\geq 0$ or, when $x<0$, $-x>0$. Thus, $0\leq \max\{x,-x\}$, so the extra $0$ is ok.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and  $|x|=\max\{-x,-42,x\}$.

Comment: Ah, the negative answer!